# mod_rewrite rule for a variable containing a minus sign in URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this regex:

```
^(.*)\/\?datum\=(.*)\.(.*)\.\-(.*)$
```

which perfectly matches an URL like:

```
http://www.example.com/sub/page/?datum=1.3.-0002
```

But when I use it as mod_rewrite rule, it just does't get fired.

All I need is to through a 404 error whenever there is a negate year in the "datum" variable in the URL.

I tried something like

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/\?datum\=(.*)\.(.*)\.\-(.*)$ -[R=404]
```

but it didn't work.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You need to match against `%{QUERY_STRING}` in `RewriteCond` , its not accessable in `RewriteRule`

Comment: oh man. Sorry sometimes you can't see the forest anymore because of all the trees. Thanks!